# App Links inside Custom Tabs in the same app

Tags: android, applinks, android-customtabs

I am facing a problem where I'm loading some web pages in `Custom Tabs`, and I want to use `App Links` when going to a certain page to open the native app. From my investigation, it looks like if the page is open with `Custom Tabs` in the same application (same package name) as the settings for the `App Links`, it does not work.

To give you the real life example, I am using `Custom Tabs` for a `"Sign up"` flow, letting the user to enter his credentials in a web page, but when going to the next page where it should tell the user to check his email for the confirmation, I want to take the user to the native app, to a custom activity with the `Android App Links`.

Any suggestions of how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem in my case. If you run into the same problem, check that all your intent filers are verified on the domain.